# Flutter Search Delegate filter data with first charater capitalised

Tags: flutter, dart

As it can be seen from the code snippet attached below the list I am filtering data on has elements which start with a capital letter. Now when I open the delegate, by default the keyboard opens up without default caps lock (In other words user inputs small characters). I want to filter data whether the user starts with a uppercase letter or small case. I've tried basic conditions, e.g., query interpolation by making the first character uppercase using if else check but I am unable to get the desired result.
Can someone please tell me the correct approach to do this.

```
    // I've tried query = query[0].toUpperCase() + query.substring(1) while handling the edge case but this doesn't work
    final suggestions = query.isEmpty
        ? cities
        : cities
            .where((element) =>
                element.contains(query) && element.startsWith(query))
            .toList();
```

Full Code:

```
class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  final cities = [
    "Agra",
    "Ahmedabad",
    "Amsterdam",
    "Antalya",
    ....
  ];

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = "";
        },
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: AnimatedIcon(
        icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
        progress: transitionAnimation,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {

    final suggestions = query.isEmpty
        ? cities
        : cities
            .where((element) =>
                element.contains(query) && element.startsWith(query))
            .toList();

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          close(context, suggestions[index]);
        },
        leading: Icon(Icons.location_city),
        title: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
              text: suggestions[index].substring(0, query.length),
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 17),
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                    text: suggestions[index].substring(query.length),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
              ]),
        ),
      ),
      itemCount: suggestions.length,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Achive that by the following code. with the help of `toLower()` method of `String`.

```
final suggestions = query.isEmpty
        ? cities
        : cities
            .where((element) =>
                element.toLowerCase().contains(query) && element.startsWith(query))
            .toList();
```

Comment: I didn't notice that it's easier the other way round.